# Passing a variable in postgres typecast

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do the following in Postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM table_one
INNER JOIN table_two ON table_one.id = table_two.table_one_id
WHERE (table_one.some_value > length('((-1,0),(table_two.x,table_two.y))'::lseg))
```

Obviously this doesn't work so my question is how do you do something like this?

`'((-1,0),(%,%))'::lseg , table_two.x , table_two.y`

or

`'((-1,0),('|| table_two.x ||',('|| table_one.x || '))'::lseg`

Comment: The second one should work… What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I am getting this `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type lseg`  also the x and y columns are floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your second suggestion work by bracketing it more clearly - casting takes precedence to concatenation so it is trying to cast '))' to an lseg. If you bracket the concatenation before casting it the statement will work ...

```
length(('((-1,0),('|| table_two.x ||','|| table_two.y || '))')::lseg)
```

But it would be neater to use the fields values in type conversion functions. At least that way the error message would make more sense if there were any.

In this case define the lseg with two points. Build one of the points is built from a literal and one from the fields in a table.

```
length(lseg('(-1,0)'::point, point(table_two.x, table_two.y)))
```

Or both from numeric values, which I think looks best and also happens to be shortest

```
length(lseg(point(-1,0), point(table_two.x, table_two.y)))
```